# jquery add image to list item once when all form fields are completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I'm having 4 list items on left hand side of the page (Left Navigation), and in the work area we are having 4 forms.

When we click on each list item it shows only one form.

Here I need a tick mark (using Jquery/ JavaScript) for each list item when all the respective form fields are filled (like a complete state).

Please help me in this scenario by using any jquery / javascript plugins.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: Please mention full details what you actually want ?

Comment: do you want something like these ? . [Click here JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/higunjan/RAEtg/26/)

Comment: What he wants is the following: He has a left navigation menu with 4 menu items that correspond to 4 forms. When a form is filled completely, the respective navigation item should receive a checkmark next to it. This way he can look at the left menu and see which of the forms have been filled.

Comment: @ John Kapantzakis: Hi, so far I've tried with form field input id based condition. like if(document.getElementById('fname1').value != "") && ... etc..

Comment: @Piwwoli: Hi sir you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can add check-box in list and using jQuery. you can check form is completely filled by this function:

function validateForm() {
  var isValid = true;
  $('.form-field').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() === '' )
        isValid = false;
  });
  return isValid;
}

and when function returns true then check the corresponded check-box
$('#checkboxId').prop('checked', true);
you can add a anchor(a) tag as well as add class(having image of tick) when above function return true

I hope this would be help full.
```

Comment: Basically I don't want any checkboxes in list items. When ever my form elements gets filled, automatically a tick mark should appear in the respective list item.

Comment: then use this http://jsfiddle.net/X3zEq/7/    
you have to check the form completely filled in or not by the function I show in the answer

Comment: Ya thnx. it works my expectations are like this https://jsfiddle.net/RaghuM/1dt6oyr1/
I've used validateForm function onblur of each field.